# Optimizing a REST Api call

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

I am working on a legacy code base which is using a call to download a file. The best thing would be to make it async, but thats not an option for time being.

the other option is to optimize the backend to fix the timeout. some existing investigation revealed that there were 8 db calls to do one thing. that has been changed to 1 db call. the performance has been improved but its still at the edge. Now there are 2 other concerns that i am trying to focus on.

1. The backend uses ORM to load from prostgres into python objects. The object contain ~30 attributes. How costly it is to construct an object with these 30 values compared to 6 values (what is sent back to user)
2. There are 3 for loops (not nested though) which are used to either format, convert and transform object from one to other. with 50,000 objects, this means that 150,000 times some instructions are being run.

Now based on 1 & 2, Should the priority be fixing 2 or fixing 1. Unfortunately the way code is setup, i can't run it locally to do any benchmarks. the only way to do it is to make the code change, go through PR and deploy to staging. So i wanted to see which one to focus before deploying.

I personally think that the 3 for loops should be modified to 1. (if possible) vs the ORM optimizations. any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you shoud focus on 1. If your loops aren't nested and you don't do any very resource intensive in your loops you should be good. Remember that if you have 1000 items in your list and two nested loops, you have 1M iterations (1000²). 150k iterations isn't too bad.

On the other hand, sometimes with ORM you end up to very ineffective SQL queries. You can log queries in your database server and think could you write them better.

One typical problem with ORM is (depending on the implementation of course) that it use queries like

```
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5....48500).
```

You could easily optimize that code with subqueries like

```
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE id IN (SELECT bar_id FROM othertable)
```

I like Postgresql slow query logging feature to see what queries need to be optimized.

Comment: so when i fixed multiple queries and converted it into one, i analyzed how much time it is taking in one of the staging env. for around 15K users, it was using 1second. which is not that bad. thats one of the reason that i am not sure should i be focusing on 1 or not.